# Copy data from a text file to a directory in Linux using Python

Tags: python, linux

newish to Python here .

I would like to know how to read in data from a text file and copy it to an existing directory in Linux .

Example:

`/home/shrubbery.txt` is a file on my Linux system containing .fits files

in python

```
file = open('/home/shrubbery.txt','r')
datalist = file.readlines()
```

now I want to copy the contents of this file to a directory in Linux called `/home/farted_in_your_general_direction`

so i'm thinking :

```
import shutil
```

now i'm not sure where to go from here , tried a few things but keep getting errors that I don't fully understand .

I'm looking for something like :

```
for i in datalist:
   shutil.copy(i,'/home/farted_in_your_general_direction')
```

any ideas ???
I basically want to end up with the .fits files in the directory .

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`file.readlines`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#file.readlines) return list of strings with newlines. So you should strip the newlines.

```
for path in datalist:
    shutil.copy(path.rstrip(), '/home/farted_in_your_general_direction')
```

Instead of using `readlines`, use `for ... in <file>`, and use `with` statement. `readlines` read all lines into memory, and you don't need all that lines.

```
import shutil

with open('/home/shrubbery.txt') as f:
    for path in f:
        shutil.copy(path.rstrip(), '/home/farted_in_your_general_direction')
```

Comment: Thanks falsetru , but when i do that i get an error saying:///   [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'a_file_that_does_exist.fits'  /// The file that the error claims does not exist is the first one called from the list , it definitely does exist .

Comment: Any ideas what might be causing this or how to get around it ? Much appreciated .